# How to evaluate an implementation Master's thesis in Evaluation chapter?

Tags: thesis, masters, application, writing, evaluation

I am writing a Master's Thesis where I developed an application. The application was developed after the study of another similar application. My application does things differently but the principle is the same for both of the applications. Now I need to write an Evaluation chapter for my thesis.

So how do I evaluate my application in the Evaluation section? Is it by comparison or by mentioning my own results?

Comment: Speak to your prof, talk with your colleagues. Check out how other publications have handled a similar matter.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned that the application is similar to another previously developed application, your evaluation ideally should compare how yours stacks up to the one it is derived from. Mention what differences there are in terms of implementation, as well as what it does better, and also whatever pitfalls exist as opposed to the other application.

You want to show what you did and learned throughout the whole process, as well as what potential improvements you might make to the application in the future. Best of luck.